# Given the sizes of various intersections, find the size of the union.

Tags: combinatorics

in a certain examination, 72 candidates offered maths,  64 offered English, 62 offered French, 18 offered maths and English, 24 offered  maths and French, 20 offered English and French and 8 offered all the three subjects. how many students are there for the examination?

pls show all steps!

Comment: Have you tried drawing a Venn diagram?

Answer (score 2):

That's the so-called [principle of inclusion and exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 1):

HINTS: consider $A=$ maths, $B=$ English, $C=$ French.

So, you have $n(A)=72,n(B)=64,n(C)=62,n(A\cap B)=18,n(A\cap C)=24,n(B\cap C)=20,n(A\cap B\cap C)=8$

Now, simply use principle of inclusion and exclusion